setting up session properties for trino SQL engine in python
I am in the process of setting up a framework using trino in python. I have set up the connection as
import trino

connection = trino.dbapi.connect(host = 'presto-sql@myorg.com', port = 'fgert', catalog = 'hive',
                                 http_scheme = 'https', username = 'abcd', password = 'tigergfrt')

cursor = connection.cursor 


Here I want to set the trino properties that will help me is:

Running large queries with heavy joins
Running 1K simple select queries succesively without getting too loaded
Running long running queries for min 2 hours before giving up on the resources.
Can look up to 1500 paritions on a single select

The existing framework is in hive with the following properties :
hive.strict.checks.large.query : false
hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict
hive.execution.engine = tez
hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = false
hive.limit.query.max.table.partition = -1

I would like the community to help me in setting standard properties and properties specific to my requirements using the trino-presto connection. Though trino also supports hive engines, the aim of the framework is to replace using hive.
Also please let me know how to implement the properties in a session. The way I have found out is :
property_dict = {'optimize_has_generation':'true', 'query_max_execution_time':'1h'}
list(map(lambda x : (cursor.execute(x), cursor.fetchall()),
         [f"set session {key} = {value}" for key, value in property_dict.items()]))


What difficulty do you have with setting standard properties and properties specific to your requirements?

I am unable to find the standard properties that should be set.
